ESRI JS map with mapbox vector tile service to show dots + labels
I am trying to optimize our map by using vector tiles instead of a normal feature layer. I made a mapbox vector tile service in python using the vectortiles package, the goal is to display a circle with a label for each entry. I am able to display the circles already but I got stuck trying to add a symbol layer.
In the frontend I simply add the vectortilelayer like this:
const MVTLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
  title: title,
  url: endpoint,
  visible: true
});

MVTLayer.load().then(() => {
  this.map.add(MVTLayer);});

The backend has the following mapbox style dict, the responses on the tile request contain the label and everyhting:
{
        "version" : 8,
        "sources" : {
            "a360" : {
                "type" : "vector",
                "url" : "../../"
            }
        },
        "layers" : [
            {
                "id" : "a360-mvt",
                "type" : "circle",
                "source" : "a360",
                "source-layer" : self.id,
                "paint": {
                    'circle-color': '#1f6200',
                    'circle-radius': 4,
                    'circle-opacity': 0.9,
                    'circle-stroke-color': 'white',
                    'circle-stroke-width': 0.5
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "a360-mvt-label",
                "type": "symbol",
                "source": "a360",
                "source-layer": "Goldenrecord",
                "layout": {
                    "text-font": [
                        "Arial Regular"
                    ],
                    "text-size": 12,
                    "text-anchor": "center",
                    "text-letter-spacing": 0.1,
                    "text-line-height": 1.1,
                    "text-max-width": 10,
                    "text-field": "{_name}",
                    "text-allow-overlap": True,
                    "text-padding": 2
                },
                "paint": {
                    "text-color": "#000000", 
                    "text-halo-color": "#ffffff", 
                    "text-halo-width": 1 
                }
            }
            ]
        })

Why doesn't the symbol layer show? I have tried a lot of things but cannot make sense of this. FYI changing styles and everything works from the backend so the problem seems to be in the config.
This is the current state:


After a lot of tries I finally found a working solution. The  glyphs url has to be defined in the style dict. Sadly the map does not throw any errors on this or anything to make this clear.
So this is my final, working style dict:
"version": 8,
"sprite": "https://cdn.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/4cf7e1fb9f254dcda9c8fbadb15cf0f8/resources/styles/../sprites/sprite",
"glyphs": "https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/resources/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
"sources": {
    self.source_name: {
        "type": "vector",
        "url": "../../"
    }
},
"layers": [...]
}

